# C# Building Win 7 & 8 Apps with Visual Studio

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio

I've built a C# VS 2015 Forms App for Win10 but the customer would like version(s) for Win7 and Win8. I can download VS 2013 which should take care of Win8 but I am unsure what to so with for Win7. Apparently plenty of people till use Win7 in the music App world.

Comment: Your question makes no sense.   C# Windows Forms and WPF apps built on Windows 10 with VS 2015 will work on Windows 7, if you select .net framework 3.5.  It may require that they install some .net components or windows 7 updates.

Comment: It does make sense when one considers I don't have a clue about these matters!

Comment: There's no excuse for not knowing how to google, friend.

Comment: Need to bail on the MS C# nastiness ASAP

Comment: C# is pretty nice.  Have fun.

Comment: @WarrenP I now agree :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

don't create windows universal app or windows metro app, just create windows Form application or WPF application using don.net framework 3.5. That will run every platform you have mentioned